# Do we need the [version] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's currently 47 questions tagged with [version](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version).

Although some questions might be in regards to different versions of software, I don't think tagging them with "version" adds anything constructive, and is very vague.  I propose the removal of the following tags for that reason:

[version](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version) [versions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/versions) [versioning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/versioning) [version-number](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version-number) [previous-versions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/previous-versions)

Again, these tags don't really allude to what the question is even asking.  You know it's *something* about a version, but does that really help to categorize these questions?  Even if a question is about a particular version of something, the version itself is usually explicitly specified in the tag.

---

After some review, I also think that [versioning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/versioning) should become a synonym of [version-control](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version-control).

---

Lastly, I've been going through a few questions, and have noticed some in regards to the version/edition of Windows.  I created a new tag called [windows-edition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-edition), to further categorize these questions (example [1](https://superuser.com/questions/253282/how-to-change-windows-7-edition-from-ultimate-to-ultimate-n), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/44752/how-can-i-determine-the-installed-edition-of-windows-xp-if-the-os-does-not-boot-u), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/74943/what-is-windows-7-anytime-upgrade), [4](https://superuser.com/questions/96092/os-version-32-bit-or-64-bit)).

Comment: Just a quick FYI, lots of retagging like this floods the front page with your edits and pushes new content away. Could you try to space them out a bit please, so that users can see get their new content seen as is appropriate.

Comment: @DMA57361 sorry, that's a good point - I'll try to avoid doing that in the future.

Comment: `created a new tag called windows-edition` - why??? I don't see it making any sense

Comment: @Sathya that [is how Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/features/2009/feb09/02-03Win7SKU-QA.mspx) refers to the different versions of Windows.

Comment: @Breakthrough it's still not relevant. We had edition-specific tags, but they weren't useful and have been added as a synonym http://superuser.com/tags/windows-7/synonyms

Comment: Should [tag:windows-edition] then become another synonym of [tag:windows-7]?  I just think that tagging something as [tag:windows-edition] is more specific then just tagging it as [tag:version] or [tag:windows-7], but I'm open to your opinion/suggestion on that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My immediate take on this is:

[version-number](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version-number) is only used once, and seems relevant in that context.

[previous-versions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/previous-versions) refers to functionality provided by Windows to roll-back files; this tag is valid.

*[versions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/versions)* is already a synonym of [version](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version), so doesn't really exist.

[version](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version) (and so *[versions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/versions)*), along with [versioning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/versioning), should *probably* all be synonyms to either [version-number](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version-number) or [version-control](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version-control), which are much more explicit. However, there's going to be a manual retagging job to be done here as I suspect many of the current questions are misusing them, but many will need saving.

Comment: There's actually quite a bit of questions tagged [tag:version] that don't relate to [tag:version-control], like [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/252614/microsoft-net-framework-versions) or [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/248025/how-can-i-get-the-version-number-of-my-installed-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu), so I think you're right that it would have to be a manual retag job.  I can start removing them from questions that don't relate to version control, but want a few more opinions before taking any action.

Comment: Well, I'm imaging that those currently tagged with [tag:version] will map to either [tag:version-number] or [tag:version-control]... I guess more investigation is needed on the main usage before any synonym appears.

Comment: Sorry, one more comment in regards to [tag:previous-versions] - don't you think that those questions should be tagged as [tag:volume-shadow-copy] or [tag:windows-backup]?  I just think the tag name itself is very ambiguous.

Comment: @Breakthrough you can have the Previous Versions functionality without Windows Backup, but previous-versions → VSC *might* be OK. My first reaction is "no", but I can't put my finger on why...