# Burn [version-number], [updates] and related tags

Tags: discussion, status-planned, tag-cleanup-request

BUMP: I started to write a new question about [version](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version), then discovered that it had been [raised 5 yrs ago](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3024/do-we-need-the-version-tag), when there were 47 questions, but not resolved.  Then I found this question from 2 yrs ago, which got the official go-ahead (although the tag is actually used for a wider range of meanings even than described here).  The [version](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version) tag, alone is now up to 131 questions.  Just wanted to bump this in case anybody has input on cleaning up the collection of tags relating to version, version numbers, updates, version control, previous version, etc., etc.

---

I've found that we have a few tags to do with 'updating software':

- [version](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version)
- <strike>version-number</strike>
- [updates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/updates)
- [software-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-update)
- [auto-updates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/auto-updates)
- <strike>automatic-updates</strike>

are all meta tags that mean different things between different software, platforms, devices etc. In other words

- They don't provide a useful filter to the questions, there's no area of expertise.
- Questions about updating some software or device will state as much in the title/body, there's no info being lost.

Note that I've left off [windows-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-update) and [google-updates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-updates) as I believe they represent specific areas of expertise, however [google-updates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-updates) *could* be renamed to remove the 's'

Thoughts?

Comment: I would have hoped that [software-update] was more related to OS X, where it's actually called like this. Seeing that it isn't, I believe that these tags all need to go.

Comment: @slhck - Hmm. Perhaps a retag of the OSX ones to something like [osx-software-update], to avoid [software-update] being used generically?

Comment: That would be possible. Much like Windows Update, it'd then be specific and unambigous. We'd have to blacklist the other tags though; I'm sure someone will start creating them again at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree.

1. Blacklisting [version-number](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version-number), [updates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/updates), [software-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-update), [auto-updates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/auto-updates), and [automatic-updates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/automatic-updates) and then
2. Manual cleanup of all of them into [osx-software-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-software-update), [windows-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-update) and [google-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-update) should be enough.

That way unambiguous tags stay.

Comment: I agree with your suggestions except purging `auto-updates` or `software-update` (whichever fits best in this situation), since software updates aren't limited to Windows, Mac OS X, Google's software, etc. There's no way to have tags available for all applicable `[application]-update`.

Comment: @zyboxenterprises - that's the point, 99% of applications **don't need** an [x-update] tag. The question will do just fine only being tagged with the application name. Larger updaters like the OS ones have fail codes, error scenarios, rollback functionality - stuff we can help with - they **do** deserve their own tag