# Time to downgrade [upgrade]

Tags: discussion, status-planned, tag-cleanup-request

I propose we clean up [upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/upgrade). It is a meta tag that is bloated and all over the place content-wise. There are questions about upgrading operating systems, RAM, software, etc. Furthermore, some are about the process of upgrading, others about problems that occurred during or following an upgrade. It's a mess and generally useless.

I suggest we burn it to the ground.

Comment: Agreed for the same reasons as the [update](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8354/burn-version-number-updates-and-related-tags) tag, It should just be burned outright :)

Comment: How would questions about upgrades in any sense be differentiated from questions that have nothing to do with upgrades?  Are you proposing to replace it with several tags that are more specific?

Comment: @fixer1234 No, I'm suggesting that we do away with the tag and just remove it from all questions without replacement. Questions about upgrading should be tagged with the appropriate tag for whatever is being upgraded, whether it's memory or an OS. Those tags provide all the information and classification that is needed to help the right people find these questions.

Comment: An Upgrade tag is useful information.  There is a common set of questions/issues that deal specifically with upgrades, and the experience/expertise doesn't necessarily lie with the same people who might be the experts on how to use the features.  If nothing else, it is a heads up as to the nature of the question for someone who either does or doesn't want to answer upgrade questions.  The issue raised in your question was insufficient specificity.  That doesn't make it worthless and the answer would seem to be to break it into more specific tags. Discard:Keep:Subdivide = bad:good:better.

Comment: @fixer1234 I really don't think [ubuntu-upgrade] provides anything more useful than [ubuntu] by itself. Or [memory-upgrade] and its ilk. You should totally write up an answer and give your defense/proposal though so we can get more community response.

Answer (score -2):

This is an example of why there is both vanilla and chocolate ice cream.  I find upgrade to be a useful tag.  There is a particular subset of issues and questions that deal with upgrading anything that is different from the issues related to, say, using the features.  Also, the people with first-hand experience and expertise with using features are not necessarily the same as for upgrades.

The issue Excellll raises is that the upgrade tag is not specific enough.  The solution to that is not to eliminate it, which makes the question even less specific,  but to make it more specific.  I would agree that it should not be used as the only tag, it should be used exclusively in combination with a subject matter tag.  Handle that by either replacing the stand-alone tag with combination tags or include hint information advising the poster to mate it with the appropriate subject tag.

As far as the tags including issues related to the upgrade process as well as problems during or following an upgrade, I see that as appropriate for an upgrade tag.  That's what I would expect to find covered by such a tag.

Comment: I see from the downvotes (and the upvotes on the question), that my opinion is clearly in the minority.  It would be helpful to the discussion if downvoters could clarify what aspect of the answer is unuseful (e.g., suggested solution is not a good one, the upgrade tag is not useful to be retained, etc.).